# "FBSDKPackage" undefined with React Native Facebook SDK in Android

Tags: android, react-native

I'm attempting to get a quick React Native Android app off the ground. It'll need signing in with Facebook, so I'm following this guide to that end.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/react-native/getting-started-android/

Unfortunately, this looks to be out of date, as `ReactActivity.java` doesn't expose a `getPackages` method. Additionally, the `FBSDKPackage` is also missing. I'm using React Native version 0.29.

```
package com.myapplication;
```

import android.content.Intent;

import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
    CallbackManager mCallbackManager;

```
/**
 * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript.
 * This is used to schedule rendering of the component.
 */
@Override
protected String getMainComponentName() {
    return "MyApplication";
}

@Override
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
    mCallbackManager = new CallbackManager.Factory().create();
    ReactPackage packages[] = new ReactPackage[]{
            new MainReactPackage(),
            new FBSDKPackage(mCallbackManager), // <-- Cannot resolve symbol 'FBSDKPackage'
    };
    return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(packages);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

}

Anyone have any experience with this?

Thanks!
Chris

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?? Please reply

Comment: I did not. Moved on to another project.

Answer (score 1):

Got this FBSDKPackage missing issue too and just solved the problem by adding this line to the import section of MainApplication.java:

```
import com.facebook.reactnative.androidsdk.FBSDKPackage;
```

Found this from the documentation on github:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 1):

For some reason react-native-fbsdk (react native 0.47.1) won't create module `compile project(':react-native-fbsdk')` so I had to clone this project https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk and import it myself with Android Studio. And of course add `import com.facebook.reactnative.androidsdk.FBSDKPackage;`

Comment: this answer is correct and I added the above git module to my project and then compiled it to get the FBSDKPackage. Thanks bro.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, i need to edit manually in app/build.gradle by adding `react-native-fbsdk` as dependencies

```
dependencies {
     ...
     implementation project(':react-native-fbsdk')
}
```

then run the android again.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem like you. I have succeeded on compiling the project **without** `FBSDKPackage` and I couldn't find any solution for that.

For the other parts, if `rnpm` didn't work (in my case it didn't), you first need to update dependencies in build.gradle (Module: app) file and add

```
compile "com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)"
```

After the sync process finishes, update your *MainApplication.java* (not MainActivity) such that it has these methods.

**MainApplication.java**

```
public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication { 

private static CallbackManager mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

  protected static CallbackManager getCallbackManager() {
    return mCallbackManager;
  }

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    protected boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage()
      );
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
      return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
      super.onCreate();
      // Initialize the SDK before executing any other operations,
      FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
      AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
  }
}
```

and in your MainActivity.java, you need to update onActivityResult such that it uses MainApplication's callback manager's onActivity result.

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
   MainApplication.getCallbackManager().onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: Did you remove the import of the fbsdkpackage too?